# How do i add to the List<FileInfo> also the size of each file as a text?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
files = new DirectoryInfo(@"d:\").GetFiles("*.avi").Where(f => f.Length <= 70 * 1024 * 1024).ToList();
```

For example the first item I see it now in the List like:

```
{test.avi}
```

How can I make that I will see also the size of each file, something like:

```
{test.avi} {23MB}
```

Comment: `.Where().Select(f=>new {Name=f.Name,Size = f.Length})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `files` will be a `List<FileInfo>`, not a `List<string>`. To convert the `FileInfo` into a `string` of your own choice, use `Select`:

```
files = new DirectoryInfo(@"d:\").GetFiles("*.avi").Where(f => f.Length <= 70 * 1024 * 1024).Select(f => f.Name + " " + (f.Length / 1048576) + " MB").ToList();
```

If you need more options (say, kB) the code inside the `Select` will be more complicated. An often forgotten feature of LINQ is that you can use complete delegates inside LINQ methods:

```
.Select((f) => {
    var s = f.Name + " ";
    if (f.Length > 1048576) {
        return s + (f.Length / 1048576) + " MB";
    } else {
        return s + (f.Length / 1024) + " kB";
    }
})
```

Comment: You right files is List<FileInfo>  and i'm getting error on the line in your solution with the DirectoryInfo: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.IO.FileInfo>'

Comment: Then you have to change the type of `files` to `List<string>`.

Comment: Glorfindel it's working changing files to List<string> now i'm getting the size results in MB but some of them are 0 i see 0MB. How do i make that the sizes for each file will be display as MB for example: 0.2MB 0.7MB 77MB in this format ?

Answer (score 1):

```
files = new DirectoryInfo(@"d:\").GetFiles("*.avi").Where(f => f.Length <= 70 * 1024 * 1024).Select(f=> new {f.Name,f.Length})).ToList();
```

Comment: files is List<FileInfo> not List<string> my mistake. And i'm getting error on the line: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.IO.FileInfo>'

Comment: since you want costomized information & not the fileInfo object, I think you need to change the type of fileinfo.

Comment: Nikita it's working changing files to List<string> now i'm getting the size results in bytes. How do i make that the sizes for each file will be display as MB for example: 0.2MB 0.7MB 77MB in this format ?

Comment: The System.IO.FileInfo.Length property will give you the file size in bytes. Divide by 1,048,576 (1024 x 1024) to get the size in megabytes.

Comment: Nikita i did it. But what i wanted is that files size under 1MB to be show as 0.1MB or 0.5MB or 0.7MB and files that the size is large then 1MB to show only the complete number like: 1MB or 5MB or 66MB now when i did this divide by 1,048,576 i'm getting in some results 0MB

Comment: can you share few values for conversion.